# Docusign EnvelopeSummary return custom fields

Tags: docusignapi

This is with the REST api and the GitHub C# client. I create an envelope and send it off using the CreateEnvelope call.  I see the deserialize calls JsonConvert.DeserializeObject on the content using the EnvelopeSummary model and it works as expected. Can EnvelopeSummary return what it does now, but also custom fields if I supplied them. I can make an additional call with the envelopeid to get this info. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: You have just created the envelope with Custom fields. Don't you already have the custom field info. Why do you want to make an additional call?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a separate API call to retrieve the envelope custom fields.
 ([listCustomFields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/list/))

As per the API documentation, CreateEnvelope returns the [envelopeSummary](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/envelopeSummary) object which contains the following four properties

- envelopeId
- status
- statusDateTime
- uri

Here is a sample response.

```
{
  "envelopeId": "91d26c0d-2e5f-40d9-bf5e-de19539d5ebf",
  "uri": "/envelopes/91d26c0d-2e5f-40d9-bf5e-de19539d5ebf",
  "statusDateTime": "2017-01-24T18:33:06.8230000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Connect publishing service.  Implement a "Connect Listener" (a Web application) and register to receive push envelope status messages, which include the envelope custom fields.

Using Connect is considered a "best practice" and does not use any API calls (does not impact your quota, does not require an API Certification).  Go to the DocuSign Dev Center and look for info on Connect or "Webhooks".